# Strange behavior of GLSL array-element-operator on sampler2D array

Tags: arrays, opengl, glsl

I'm currently writing a simple shader and ran into a strange problem.

I'm basically rendering a bunch of textures using a sampler2D array from which I select the texture needed.

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

in DATA
{
    vec4 position;
    vec4 color;
    vec2 texCoord;
    flat int texID;
} fs_in;

uniform sampler2D textures[16];

void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = fs_in.color;
    if (fs_in.texID > 0)
    {
        texColor = fs_in.color * texture(textures[fs_in.texID - 1], fs_in.texCoord);
    }
    color = texColor;
}
```

This code, however, gives me strange artifacts on the textures:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGm0U.png)

### Now here is the strange part:

Replacing

```
texColor = fs_in.color * texture(textures[fs_in.texID - 1], fs_in.texCoord);
```

with the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    if (fs_in.texID - 1 == i)
        texColor = fs_in.color * texture(textures[i], fs_in.texCoord);
```

fixed the problem: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDAfs.png)

Also, this problem is only appearing on my AMD based computer using OpenGL 4.5.13469 Compatibility Profile Context 21.19.525.258

Running the original program on my Surface Pro works perfectly fine.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I have no clue why this problem is occurring or why the change fixed it. Explanation appreciated.

~ Stone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> #version 330 core
> ```

In GLSL 3.30, arrays of samplers can *only* be accessed by [constant expressions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Constant_Expression). Your shader should not have compiled.

But let's pretend that your hardware supports more than GLSL 3.30. In which case:

> ```
> textures[fs_in.texID - 1]
> ```

In GLSL 4.00+, arrays of samplers can *only* be accessed by [dynamically uniform expressions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Dynamically_Uniform_Expression). And unless you're rendering exactly one triangle, or every triangle has the same `fs_in.texID` value, that expression is *not* dynamically uniform. And I'm guessing it's not, since you didn't just use a `uniform`.

If you index an array of opaque types with an expression that is not dynamically uniform, you get undefined behavior.

> with the following
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
>     if (fs_in.texID - 1 == i)
>         texColor = fs_in.color * texture(textures[i], fs_in.texCoord);
> ```

Even this invokes undefined behavior. While the expression `i` may by itself be dynamically uniform, because that statement is only executed conditionally, that condition does not guarantee that the value of `i` used will be the same for all invocations within the invocation group.

So it's still not dynamically uniform. It's just undefined behavior that just so happened to work. There's no guarantee it will work on anything else.

You can't escape the rules; you cannot switch which texture to use in the middle of a rendering command. If that's what you really want, then you don't want an array of textures; you want an array texture:

```
uniform sampler2DArray textures;

void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = fs_in.color;
    if (fs_in.texID > 0)
    {
        texColor = fs_in.color * texture(textures, vec3(fs_in.texCoord, fs_in.texID - 1));
    }
    color = texColor;
}
```

Or, just remove the condition, make layer 0 of your texture contain only ones, and always fetch from the texture (since doing it conditionally [may require you to manually provide derivatives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Non-uniform_flow_control)):

```
uniform sampler2DArray textures;

void main()
{
    color = fs_in.color * texture(textures, vec3(fs_in.texCoord, fs_in.texID));
}
```

Comment: Ok so I do need a constant index, I got that. I did some digging and according to [GLES specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf) in The Appendix, section 5: "The following are constant-index-expressions: [...] • Loop indices as defined in section 4 [...]". Doesn't that mean that iterating over an array of textures is valid? (I totally understand using sampler2DArray is better, just curious)

Comment: @LevyEhrstein: That's OpenGL ES 2.0; it has different rules.